# Horizontal Bar chart Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bar-chart, ios-charts

I want it like this:

[image]

But what I can do is, how to get rid of little red label:
[image]

Core code for the chart:

```
var barchart = [BarChartDataEntry]()
// some values
barchart.append(value1)
barchart.append(value2)
barchart.append(value3)

let barData = BarChartDataSet(values: barchart, label: "")
barData.colors = [NSUIColor.red]
let data = BarChartData(dataSet: barData)
data.barWidth = 0.35
cell.barChart.data = data
cell.barChart.scaleYEnabled = false
cell.barChart.chartDescription?.text = ""
cell.barChart.scaleXEnabled = false
cell.barChart.pinchZoomEnabled = false
cell.barChart.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
cell.barChart.rightAxis.enabled = false
cell.barChart.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
cell.barChart.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
cell.barChart.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
cell.barChart.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
cell.barChart.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
cell.barChart.leftAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
cell.barChart.animate(yAxisDuration: 1.5, easingOption: .easeInOutQuart)
return cell
```

I would like to set max value and make labels rounded as in the image above. I am using https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the similar UI by using the [UIProgressView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiprogressview)

First, you can set the Label on top, then a UIProgressView and repeat the same. For other two progresses.

You can add the proper constraints and achieve it.

Refer this [Sample Demo](https://github.com/gordoneliel/LinearProgressBar) for achieving the same.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you help with implementation? I have never used UIProgressView.

Comment: checkout the reference link to achieve the same. the class is IBDesignable, so you can use them directly with the storyboard and can bind the outlets to it.

Comment: @NaberApp _Please_ read the documentation before asking someone else to do the work for you.

Comment: @Bhavin Kansagara thank you. Do you know how to animate LinearProgressBar?

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line where you are setting chartView

```
cell.barChart.legend.enabled = false
```

It works for me.

Comment: How to add grey color like in the image, how to set max value

Comment: To set Max/Min Values
cell.barChart.leftAxis.axisMinimum = MIN-VALUE
cell.barChart.leftAxis.axisMaximum = MAX-VALUE

Answer (score 0):

Use **UIProgressView** component in storyboard and create the outlet

```
@IBOutlet var progressViewWalk: UIProgressView!
```

You can set the required progress by:-

```
progressViewWalk.progress = Float(YOURValue)/100
```

Set your required Track tint color Progress tint color in **`Attribute Inspector`**.